# Cisco AS5300 high temperature issue?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, environmental-monitoring

Today I have configured SNMP sensors for the environment parameters on Cisco AS 5300, but I have get shocked that the system health temperature is 29C/84F and when I check the output from the  device console I get the below :

```
Temperature:
        Temperature Reading:
                Temperature at inlet is measured as 24C/75F.
                Temperature at outlet is measured as 29C/84F.
        Temperature State:
                Temperature is in normal state.
```

so please I want some advise if this output is normal or there is some  weak fan need to be replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temperature is perfectly normal. Depending on where it is placed and if it has a fan coil available i actually think it looks perfect. Cisco's best practice for operating temperatures is a room temperature not exceeding 27C.

You can see Cisco's whitepaper for Data Center installations and temperatures here:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/data-center-virtualization/unified-computing/white_paper_c11-680202.pdf